# a href doesn't work in a pushed footer

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, href

I would like to place some links in that footer that doesn't work as they should do. it seems like that they are not clickable and i have no clue why this is happening.

The footer itself is located at the end of the site and will be forced to stay at the bottom by a pushed div. My whole div-arrangement is like:

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="push"></div>        
</div>
<div class="footer">
<div id="about">
    <div id="list">
        <span class="up">1. row</span>
        <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="/one.php">one</a></li>
            <li><a href="/two.php">two</a></li>
            <li><a href="/three.php">three</a></li>
            <li><a href="/four.php">four</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="legals">
    <div id="list2">
        <span class="down">2.row</span>
        <ul class="nav2">
            <li><a href="/five.php">five</a></li>
            <li><a href="/six.php">six</a></li>
            <li><a href="/seven.php">seven</a></li>
            <li><a href="/eight.php">eight</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/7kXJu/)

Why is this href not working?

---

okay, thanks to everyone. adding z-index doesnt work in this case because when adding this, the whole content of the wrapper wont be displayed because of using another couple other z-index in that class. so the solution is removing position:relative. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `z-index:-1` in your `.wrapper`

**As like this**

```
.wrapper{
z-index:-1;
}
```

***[Demo-one](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/7kXJu/8/)***

### --------

Or **Second Option** is

**Remove** `position:relative` on this class `.wrapper`

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/7kXJu/5/)***

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your element with class `push` is overlapping your footer, therefor, when you click on what you think is the footer links, you actually click on the push-element.

Does your wrapper have to be relatively positioned?

If not, you can just remove `position: relative` from the wrapper class, and you are good to go:

[**Working example**](http://jsfiddle.net/7kXJu/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Thats because `<ul class="nav">` and `<ul class="nav2">` have got on overlay, which menas something is staying on top of them. You can give absolute posiiton to your ul that has links and higher z-index to stack them up, so they become clickable.

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/7kXJu/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Add `z-index` to wrapper

```
.wrapper {
    position:relative;
    width: 960px;
    height: auto !important;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -80px;
    z-index:-1
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7kXJu/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

In your css `position` of `wrapper class div` is `relative`. that is main reason behind links are not clickable so please add `position:relative` to `footer` class div.

Answer (score -1):

What you need wrapper?
If delete "position: relative;" from wrapper class it works. (or change z-index)